# PIC16f877a Build failed

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I was able to compile the program below on my desktop or another PC successfully.  However, I cannot compile this code on my laptop. I tried to re-install the software with the same version as I have installed on the desktop. It gives me the same error but will compile with the code marked "Normal LED Program" below. How can I fix this?

**Program that fails to compile**:

```
#include<pic.h>
__CONFIG(0x3F3A);

main()
{
    TRISB=0;
    PORTB=0;

    PSA=0;
    PS2=0;
    PS1=0;
    PS0=0;
    TMR0=6;
    T0CS=0;
    T0SE=0;
    TMR0IE=1;

    int count=0;

    while(1)
    {
        if(TMR0IF==1)
        {
            TMR0IF=0;

            count=count++;
            if(count==2000)
            {
                RB0=~RB0;
                count=0;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Warning Error:

[image]

**Normal LED Program (compiles successfully)**:

```
#include <pic.h>
__CONFIG(0x3F38);
main()
{
    TRISB=0;
    PORTB=0;
    while(1)
    {
        PORTB=0x01;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in `__CONFIG`?

Comment: @Jongware, `__CONFIG()` is a Microchip intrinsic for the HI-TECH compiler used to burn the device configuration bits in flash.  It looks like both the "Normal LED Program" and the one that is failing are valid configurations.  You have to look at the datasheet to see what the settings are.  The only difference between these two are the oscillator bits - shouldn't affect the compilation though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this compiler does not support C99 code, specifically declaring variables in the middle of a block. Move the `count` declaration to the beginning of the `main` block, like so:

```
main()
{
    int count = 0;

    TRISB = 0;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's Work Properly :)

Comment: @whywhy, You may want to take a look at the compiler and see if there is a flag to support C99.  If it is set on your PC and not on your laptop, that may be why you get different results with the same code.

Comment: Hi embedded_guy, i not sure is the C99 problem because i solve it by reinstall the software. Maybe The inline function error because of C99 not work properly in previous MPlab version. Thanks for the information about c99.